# Cross reference list or records against eachother in presto

Tags: sql, presto

I am trying to cross reference a table against itself.

I have a table of holiday destinations, and unique user IDs who looked at those destinations.

I want to, for each destination (e.g. A) cross reference it against all other destinations (e.g. B - Z) and count how many user who looked at A also looked at B - something like this:

```
Location 1 | Location 2 | Users looking at 1 | Users looking at 2 who looked at 1
```

So far I can get Location 1 and users looking at location 1:

```
select * from (select A.location, count(distinct(A.user)) as the_count from (
    SELECT 
      location, distinct(user)
    FROM
      search
  ) as A group by A.location
```

I think I need to do a conditional join of some kind, I just can't work out how, joining each result from that select against every other result, and including a subset from A where the users have looked for the location in the first column.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

PrestoDB is pretty close to standard SQL.  In standard SQL, you can do this as:

```
select l1.location as location1, l2.location as location1,
       count(distinct s2.user)
from location l1 join
     location l2
     on l1.location < l2.location left join
     search s1
     on s1.location = l1.location left join
     search s2
     on s2.location = l2.location and
        s2.user = s.user
group by l1.location, l2.location;
```